# How do I get the contents of an email in gwt?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have the following code runnning on the server over gwt rpc:

```
public class MailHandlerServlet  extends HttpServlet{

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    doPost(req, resp);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, req.getInputStream());
} catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I don't know a function that parse `MimeMessage`. How do I get the content of `MimeMessage`?

here the simple code I write but it's not working:

```
Object content = message.getContent();
if(content instanceof Multipart){
             Multipart mp = (Multipart)content;
             int count3 = mp.getCount();
             for(int i = 0;i < count3;i++){
                BodyPart p = mp.getBodyPart(i);
                if(p.isMimeType("text/plain")){ 
                    TextBody data = (TextBody) p.getContent();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    data.writeTo(baos);
                    String datafull = new String(baos.toByteArray());  
                    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
                    out.print(datafull.toString());
                }
```

Comment: This is not GWT-RPC. You just sub-classed HttpServlet, so this has nothing to do with GWT.

Comment: You should add the Tag 'google-app-engine'. Because that is the important information you missed to provide. There still is no GWT included at this point.

Comment: I think it's about time you posted what "not working" means. Do you get an exception? If yes, POST IT.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried MimeMessage.getContent() ?

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getContent()

Comment: I use library javax.mail so do you have another link for this?thank

Comment: What part of `javax.mail` is not in the API for the package, `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage`? I don't think another link will help.

Comment: yep i think a method is getContent but i try many time it doesn't work :(